# Confusion on the computation of boundary map in the cellular homology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am a first-time learner of homology, and I was confused when I tried to prove the homology of a $2-$dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^{2}$.

Firstly, from my class, the boundary map $\partial_{k}:C_{k}(X)\longrightarrow C_{k-1}(X)$ is a $p\times q$ matrix where $p=$ the number of $k-$dimensional cells and $q=$ the number of $k-1$dimensional cells. Then, $\partial_{k}=(a_{ij})_{\substack{1\leq i\leq p \\ 1\leq j\leq q}}$ and the entries are defined as  $a_{ij}:=\deg(q_{j}\circ g_{i}),$ where $$q_{j}\circ g_{i}:\partial e_{i}^{k}=\mathbb{S}_{i}^{k-1}\longrightarrow_{g_{i}}X^{k-1}\longrightarrow_{q_{j}}\dfrac{X^{k-1}}{\Big(X^{k-2}\cup e_{1}^{k-1}\cup\cdots\cup e_{j-1}^{k-1}\cup e_{j+1}^{k-1}\cup\cdots\cup e_{q}^{k-1}\Big)}\cong S_{j}^{k-1}=\partial e_{j}^{k}.$$

Then, I tried to use this definition to compute the homology of $\mathbb{T}^{2}$, as follows:

---

Recall that standard rectangle we used to construct $\mathbb{T}^{2}$, and it has a cell complex structure as follows: these two horizontal lines are $e_{a}^{1}$, and the vertical lines are $e_{b}^{1}$, with four attaching dot $e^{0}$.

Then, we can write $X^{0}=e^{0}$ and $X^{1}=e^{0}\cup_{f_{a}}e_{a}^{1}\cup_{f_{b}}e_{b}^{1}$ with the attaching map $$f_{a}:\partial e_{a}^{1}=\mathbb{S}_{a}^{0}\longrightarrow X^{0}\ \text{and}\ f_{b}:\partial e_{b}^{1}=\mathbb{S}_{b}^{0}\longrightarrow X^{0}.$$ Note that $X^{1}$ is the figure eight with $e_{b}^{1}$ and $e_{a}^{1}$ as those two ``circles'' and $e^{0}$ as the attaching point.

Then, $X^{2}=X^{1}\cup_{g}e^{2}$, with the attaching map $g:\partial e^{2}=\mathbb{S}^{1}\longrightarrow X^{1}.$

With this cell complex structure,  we see that $$C_{0}(X)=\mathbb{Z}e^{0}\cong\mathbb{Z},$$ $$C_{1}(X)=\mathbb{Z}e_{a}^{1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_{b}^{1}\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\ \text{and}$$ $$C_{2}(X)=\mathbb{Z}e^{2}\cong\mathbb{Z}.$$

Therefore, we have the chain complex $$\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow_{\partial_{2}}\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow_{\partial_{1}}\mathbb{Z}.$$

Since there is only one $2-$dimensional cell $e^{2}$, by definition, $\partial_{2}$ is a $1\times 2$ matrix
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
\deg(q_{a}\circ g)&\deg(q_{b}\circ g)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then I got stuck, how am I supposed to express $q_{a}\circ g$ and $q_{b}\circ g$ if there is only one $2-$dimensional cell? Is it true for me to have $$q_{a}\circ g:\partial e^{2}=\mathbb{S}^{1}\longrightarrow_{g} X^{1}\longrightarrow_{q_{a}}\dfrac{X^{1}}{X^{0}\cup e_{b}^{1}}\cong \mathbb{S}^{1}=\partial e^{2}?$$ and then what degree of the composition map?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have one $0$-cell $e^0=\{0\}$, two $1$-cells $e^1_a$ and $e^1_b$ (with the only possible attaching maps), and one $2$-cell $e^2$ attached in a particular way. As you say, the entire chain complex is then

$$0\to \Bbb Z\xrightarrow{\partial_2}\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{\partial_1}\Bbb Z\to 0.$$

The boundary map $\partial_1$ is sort of unique because the zero cells are points rather than $S^0$. If your space is connected (given it is a CW complex), then $\partial_1$ is always $0$.

So really we just need to find $\partial_2$, which is a $2\times 1$ matrix. Writing $S^1$ for the boundary of $e^2$ and $\varphi\colon S^1\to S^1_a\vee S^1_b$ for the attaching map, the entries of $\partial_1$ are the degrees of the compositions
$$S^1\xrightarrow{\varphi}S^1_a\vee S^1_b\to S^1_a\quad\text{and}\quad S^1\xrightarrow{\varphi}S^1_a\vee S^1_b\to S^1_b.$$

Now the annoying part is actually computing these degrees. The point is that $S^1$ wraps around $S^1_a$ once in one direction, and then again in the opposite direction. The resulting degree is thus $0$, and similarly for the other map. Accepting this, we see $\partial_1$ is trivial, and the homology groups follow.

One way to get more rigorous when computing the entries in $\partial_1$ is to explicitly write out what the composition $S^1\to S^1_a$. Up to homotopy, it is the same as the wedge of the identity map with the antipodal map, so the degree is $1-1=0$. In practice, you can usually get away without getting too explicit.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer!

Comment: By the way, one potential typo here is that in the last 2 paragraphs, you seemed mix up the notation, we want to argue with $\partial_{2}$, but somehow you change it to $\partial_{1}$. But it does not affect my understanding. Thank you!